# How to use group By for a map in java?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, stream

I have list which contains a map List<Map<String, Object>> map has two keys which is a id and the amount. I want to sort the list descending order base on the amount key, if the amount is same for two elements in the list then sort it based on the id. How can I do this ?

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put(id, 1);
    hm.put(amount, 25000);
    list.add(hm);
```

index of list element = 1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 ,6

values for id  = 1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5, 4

values for amount = 10000, 450000, 25000, 45000, 35000, 75000

list should sorted as follows(index of list) = 6, 4 (id is large), 2, 5, 3, 1

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add [mre]. Does each map have only one entry ?

Comment: yes  just a one entry.  As i have shown in the later part of the question after every iteration map added it's object to the list . I have to sort that list based on the keys

Comment: If the map has one enrty you don't really need a map but a pair. You can use [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) which is a key-value pair, in `List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>`  For more help post mre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities, this one modifies the original list:

```
Comparator<Map<String, Object>> sortByAmount = Comparator.comparing(m -> (int) m.get("amount"));
Comparator<Map<String, Object>> sortById = Comparator.comparing(m -> (int) m.get("id"));

list.sort(sortByAmount.reversed().thenComparing(sortById));
```

If you want to preserve the original list, you can use the stream api:

```
list.stream().sorted(sortByAmount.reversed().thenComparing(sortById));
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think Using CustomObject instead of Map will be help you solve this in much easy way.

CustomObject

```
//fell free to change data type of fields as per your requirement
public class CustomObject {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer amount;

    public CustomObject(Integer id, Integer amount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Integer amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Now List will contain Object instead of Map which will make sorting much easy.

```
List<CustomObject> list=new ArrayList<>();
        CustomObject customObject1=new CustomObject(1,10000);
        CustomObject customObject2=new CustomObject(2,45000);
        CustomObject customObject3=new CustomObject(3,25000);
        CustomObject customObject4=new CustomObject(4,45000);
        CustomObject customObject5=new CustomObject(5,35000);
        CustomObject customObject6=new CustomObject(6,75000);

        list.add(customObject1);
        list.add(customObject2);
        list.add(customObject3);
        list.add(customObject4);
        list.add(customObject5);
        list.add(customObject6);

        // You can use thenComparing() as much as you required incase you want to compare with multiple field of your custom object
        // for your problem it has only two field
        Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(CustomObject::getAmount)
                .thenComparing(CustomObject::getId).reversed());

        list.forEach(x->{

            System.out.println(x.getId()+" -->" +x.getAmount());
        });
```

output:

```
6 -->75000
4 -->45000
2 -->45000
5 -->35000
3 -->25000
1 -->10000
```

Comment: yes I can do this, but in my project I'm not allowed to create a another class